# Proving the congruence of a Fibonacci Number

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $F_n$ denote the $n^{th}$ fibonacci number where $F_0 = 0, F_1 = 1$. Prove that for all primes $p > 5$, $$F_p \equiv 5^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \mod (p)$$

Comment: FWIW, by [Euler's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion) and [Quadratic Reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity) this is equivalent to: $$\begin{cases}F_p\equiv 1\pmod{p},&& p\equiv \{1,4\}\pmod{5}\\F_p\equiv -1\pmod{p},&& p\equiv \{2,3\}\pmod{5}\end{cases}$$